# Python argparse treat arguments in different ways

Tags: python, arguments, command-line-arguments, argument-passing

I want to create an optional argument, which will be the `'-- '` (double dash and a space) and get everything after it as its value. The problem is that some other optional arguments might appear after `'-- '`. I don't want these to be parsed as optional arguments, but as the values of `'-- '`. For example:

```
python prog1 --foo 1 --bar 2
```

Here `foo` and `bar` are optional arguments with values `1` and `2` respectively

```
python prog1 --foo 1 --bar 2 -- --foo 4 --bar 14
```

Here I want `foo` and `bar` that come before `'-- '` to be parsed as optional arguments. But I want `'--foo 4 --bar 14'` to be parsed as the value of the optional argument `'-- '`. I would like to do this without renaming the parameters that come after `'-- '` to `foo2` and `bar2`, if possible.

So is this possible? And how could this be implemented?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It's a complete antipattern, and will likely just confuse people (/ your future self).

Comment: @will -- This isn't a complete anti-pattern.  This is actually a relatively common way to specify arguments that will be passed to a slave program (maybe via `subprocess.Popen`).

Comment: @mgilson So i just read about this. That's news to me.

Comment: In fact, `argparse` already supports the common convention of using `--` to signal the end of option parsing.

Comment: `--` is commonly used on Unix-like OSes to separate arguments from raw input (often the raw input represents the arguments to be passed to some _other_ command, as in the case of `xargs`). See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11376/4322.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`argparse` already supports `--` as an end-of-options terminator. The only difference is that the default handling treats the following arguments individually. Suppose `prog1` simply looks like

```
import argparse

p = argparse.ArgumentParser()

p.add_argument('--foo')
p.add_argument('--bar')
p.add_argument('remaining', nargs=argparse.REMAINDER)

print p.parse_args()
```

Then the command

```
% python prog1 --foo 1 --bar 2 -- --foo 4 --bar 14
```

produces

```
Namespace(bar='2', foo='1', remaining=['--', '--foo', '4', '--bar', '14'])
```

(rather than `Namespace(..., remaining='-- --foo 4 --bar 14')`). Than can be fixed with a quick post-processing step, if necessary:

```
args = p.parse_args()
args.remaining = " ".join(args.remaining)
print args
```

Then the result is

```
Namespace(bar='2', foo='1', remaining='-- --foo 4 --bar 14')
```

Discarding the `--` argument requires some additional post-processing:

```
args = p.parse_args()
if args.remaining[0] == "--":
    args = args[1:]
```

Comment: This is brilliant -- however, I can't seem to find it in the docs.  The closest that I have been able to find is `argparse.REMAINDER`, but that doesn't seem to use the `--` separator...

Comment: See the very end of [section 15.4.4.3](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#arguments-containing) (link to the Python 2.7 version of the documentation).

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about `REMAINDER`; that seems like a better choice than `*` (at least more descriptive; I can't tell if there is a functional difference in this case.)

Comment: Nice.  Well, you have my +1 anyway -- and I learned something new.

Comment: I ran this code and my remaining was `remaining=['--', '--foo', '4', '--bar', '14']`. Note the `--` showed up in the remaining.

Comment: I have the same issue as @gsingh2011

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the [docopt](https://github.com/docopt/docopt) library can do this for you;

From the [`usage-pattern-format`](https://github.com/docopt/docopt#usage-pattern-format) section:

> "[--]". Double dash "--" is used by convention to separate positional
>   arguments that can be mistaken for options. In order to support this
>   convention add "[--]" to your usage patterns.